# How to overcome delay in navigation to other viewcontroller iOS swift?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, jsondecoder

I have recently stopped using `Alamofire` for making HTTP Networking calls as now in swift 4 Apple have introduced `Codable`-protocol which is very powerful and fast compared to `Alamofire`. Everything works fine as expected even my response in faster than before. But there is one problem. Before using `Codable` protocol for parsing data my navigation to other views used to be very fast. But now there is a slight delay in my navigation particularly when navigating to the pages where I am using `JSONDecoder` to get response. For ex: I have VC1 and VC2, VC1 is a static page where in VC2 I am using `JSONDecoder` and getting some data and displaying it in `collectionView`. Now I click on a button in VC1, It just stops for a second before going to VC2. I don't know why this is happening.

Code in VC1:

```
@IBAction func gotoProductCollectionView(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "productCollection") as! ProductCollectionViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

Code in VC2:

```
class ProductCollectionViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

@IBOutlet weak var productsTableView: UITableView! 

var productsData = [ProductData]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    getProductData()
}

func getProductData() {
    self.productsData = []
    guard let productDataURL = URL(string: "MyURL") else {return}
   DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
     do {
         let data = try Data(contentsOf: productDataURL)
         self.productsData = try 
 JSONDecoder().decode([ProductData].self, from: data)
         print(self.productsData)
         print(self.productsData.count)
         for productNames in self.productsData {
             print(productNames.product_name!)
         }
        }catch let error {
           print(error)
       }
      DispatchQueue.main.async {                
            self.productsTableView.reloadData()
        }
     }
   } 
}
```

Product Model Object:

```
struct ProductData: Codable {

var product_id: String?
var product_name: String?
var product_price: String?
var product_special_price: String?
var product_sale_of: String?
var product_brand: String?
var product_image: String?

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case product_id
    case product_name
    case product_price
    case product_special_price
    case product_sale_of
    case product_brand
    case product_image
}

init(product_id: String? = nil, product_name: String? = nil, product_price: String? = nil, product_special_price: String? = nil, product_sale_of: String? = nil, product_brand: String? = nil, product_image: String? = nil) {

    self.product_id = product_id
    self.product_name = product_name
    self.product_price = product_price
    self.product_special_price = product_special_price
    self.product_sale_of = product_sale_of
    self.product_brand = product_brand
    self.product_image = product_image
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    product_id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .product_id)
    product_name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .product_name)
    product_price = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .product_price)
    product_special_price = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .product_special_price)
    product_brand = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .product_brand)
    product_image = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .product_image)
    if let value = try? container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .product_sale_of) {
        product_sale_of = String(value)
    } else {
        product_sale_of = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .product_sale_of)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried hiding `getProductData()` to check if the delay still remains?

Comment: @Astoria I did and it is very fast as usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in this line

```
let data = try Data(contentsOf: productDataURL)
```

Obviously you download the data from internet in the `DispatchQueue.main`

You need to do it in separate background queue and then update the view from the `main` again. Don't forget to use `.async` calls.